# HTML emails doesn't display tables content in Microsoft Outlook 2010

Tags: html, html-table, html-email, outlook-2010, outlook-2019

**Problem:**
Tables content does not display properly on Desktop Microsoft Outlook 2010 and 2019. However, it looks well in other versions of Microsoft Outlook and the browser.

My snippet of code is here:

```html
<tr>
                        <td>
                            <table role="presentation" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"                          
                                style="min-width:100%; border-collapse:collapse; border:0; border-spacing:0; font-size:12px; font-family:Arial,sans-serif;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr
                                        style="padding: 0; color: white; border: 1.2px solid rgb(90, 87, 87); background: #3d3c3b !important">
                                        <td style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px; text-align: center;">No.</td>
                                        <td style=" text-align: center;">Description</td>
                                        <td style=" text-align: center;">Amount (RM)</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tr
                                    style=" padding: 0; color: white; border: 1.2px solid rgb(90, 87, 87); background: #353635 !important">
                                    <td style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px; text-align: center;">1</td>
                                    <td style=" text-align: center;">Water bill</td>
                                    <td style=" text-align: center;">78.00</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr
                                    style=" padding: 0; color: white; border: 1.2px solid rgb(90, 87, 87); background: #353635 !important">
                                    <td style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px; text-align: center;">2</td>
                                    <td style=" text-align: center;">Electricity bill</td>
                                    <td style=" text-align: center;">251.25</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr
                                    style=" padding: 0; color: white; border: 1.2px solid rgb(90, 87, 87); background: #353635 !important">
                                    <td style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px; text-align: center;">3</td>
                                    <td style=" text-align: center;">Indah water bill</td>
                                    <td style=" text-align: center;">25.50</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr
                                    style=" padding: 0; color: white; border: 1.2px solid rgb(90, 87, 87); background: #575757 !important">
                                    <th style="padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px; text-align: center;" colspan="2">
                                        Total:</th>
                                    <th style=" text-align: center;">RM 480.75</th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>                       
                    <tr>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: From the code provided, you haven't closed the very first row. Close and see if it helps

Comment: Hi Syfer, I have updated my code and closed the </tr> but the output is still the same.

Comment: try removing the !important from the background colour. Outlook will remove anything that has a !important on it inline.

Comment: I have solved this by removing !important from the background color. Thank you, Nathan.